# Handle keyboard event while submit form in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a login form and Whenever I click on the input box, the keyboard opens, but when I press the submit button, the keyboard closes first and then I press the submit button again, then the form submits. But I want that whenever I click on submit button the keyboard automatically closes and the form gets submitted at the same time.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button,KeyboardAvoidingView } from "react-native";
import { Button, Input } from "native-base";

export default class TestForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  }

  handleSignupChange = (data, text) => {
    this.setState({ [data]: text });
  };

  submitForm = () => {
      const {email,password}=this.state;
      console.log('form value',email,password);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled={true}>
        <Text> TestForm </Text>
        <Input
          onChangeText={(e) => this.handleSignupChange("email", e)}
          placeholder="email"
        />
        <Input
          onChangeText={(e) => this.handleSignupChange("password", e)}
          placeholder="password"
        />
        <Button onPress={this.submitForm} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You import the `Keyboard` from `react-native` and call it at the beginning of the function to hide your keyboard

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

submitForm = () => {
 Keyboard.dismiss
 const {email,password}=this.state;
 console.log('form value',email,password);
};
```